# I need two <select> items next to each other in my form to take up 100% of their parent DIV using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, width

I'm trying to create a search form using Bootstrap and it's all fine but I need two of the multi-option to sit next to each other and collectively take up 100% width of their containing DIV.

[image]

The orange is obviously only there to highlight what I'm trying to do.

Comment: did you try adding the span6 class to controls?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using<should have been my first question

Comment: Version 3.2. Is the span6 class from a previous version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to put those [inputs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) into a `row`, then each input div take up half of the container div using `col-*-6` (12 is the maximum set by the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) layout). That is what I did in the follow example:

**Code**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <label label-default="" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
    placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label label-default="" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
        placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label label-default="" for="username">username</label>
        <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username"
        placeholder="username">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label label-default="" for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">Check me out</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

I will add my bootply when it actually saves... but you can copy and paste it into a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#) for now to see demo.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) as a reference, you will want to put your controls into a row with the class markup for grid spans

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        your control here with style for 100% width
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        your control here with style for 100% width
    </div>
</div>
```